# Logic for view is on superView

Tags: swift, observers

Hey developers what I'm trying to achieve is set an observer or a logic to know when this view is on the superview or not

```
private var errorAlertView: ErrorAlertView?
```

I have this logic to check if the view is on superview or not

```
if errorAlertView?.superview != nil {
            //is on superview
        }else{
            //it's not on superview
        }
```

but I can only check this every time the **viewWillAppear**
what I need is to trigger a function when the alert is not on superview, is there a way to make this an observer so I can instantly run the function when this happened?

Comment: Depending from where you want to obsverve, maybe do not do `errorAlertView =` too soon. Ie, set it only when used, and delete it as soon as removed. You could then use a `didSet` on it to perform your method. Or you could use a delegate pattern or a closure to notify when it's added or removed.

Comment: thanks, what could be better? the alertview gets trigger if there's not internet or the API gets any error, with a delegate method.
so what I'm trying to achieve is show other alert view when this hides, so that's why I want to track if it's on the super view or not

Comment: but I can't think with a logic that 'tracks' the errorAlertView if was removed or not

Comment: you can check subviews of superview and if alert view doesn't exist show another alert ?\

Comment: but the better approach is show toast for Internet connectivity rather than alert.